# Samsung Smart TV address MAC

Tags: javascript, html, tizen, samsung-smart-tv

How can I get the MAC address a from Samsung Smart TV in JavaScript?

I tried the code below but nothing happens:

```
function getMAC() {
    var mac = null;
    try {
        mac = webapis.network.getMac();
    } catch (e) {
        addResult("getMAC exception [" + e.code + "] name: " + e.name 
            + " message: " + e.message);
    }

    if (null != mac) {
        addResult("[getMAC] mac: " + mac);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by nothing happens? Where is this code executed, TV or emulator?
you do not return anything in this function.

Comment: I try it both on TV and emulator and it return nothing

Comment: Your function does not contain `return` statement. you probably want to add `return mac;` in the end

Comment: I will, thank you. can I contact you in private Ivan Solntsv.

Comment: You can see the MAC adress in the Network Settings on your TV or in the router...

Comment: no I want to get throw a JavaScript code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Check you TV is running on Tizen.
2. Check config.xml has `<tizen:privilege name="http://developer.samsung.com/privilege/network.public"/>`

And... I think you already make the `addResult` function but just make it if you don't.

Comment: When I use this code on tizen samsung tv emulator without adding the privilege I get error in catch statement which is expected, but when I add this privilege and try to run the code I get `widget installation failed` error. Does the code only works for real device?